# Specifying cs file to build with dotnet CLI

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface

Suppose I have two files in my current working directory:

```
// file1.cs
Console.WriteLine("file1");
```

```
//file 2.cs
Console.WriteLine("file2");
```

In powershell, I do a `dotnet new` and delete the automatically generated `Program.cs` file. Then I do a `dotnet build` and get an error:

> Only one compilation unit can have top level statements

I understand why this occurs, but I would like to be able to have full control of which `.cs` file is being targetted, while the other ones get ignored.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to create a whole new project for every file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this with .NET doesn't seem to be possible as of now. [An issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12328) on the [dotnet/sdk GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/) has requested for this feature to be implemented.

However, you can use the C Sharp Compiler to compile a Windows executable and specify a .cs file with `csc file1.cs`

###### file1.cs:

```cs
using System;

Console.WriteLine("File 1");
```

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements

These files both use top-level statements. It implies that they both contain the `Main` method where program execution starts. You can only have one entry point. Generally, C# code is going to be contained within classes. Define a class in one (or both) files and put your methods within.

```
// Program.cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program.cs");
    }
}

// Util.cs
public class Util
{
    public static void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Util.cs");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats precisely what I dont want to do. You have misunderstood my question I'm afraid.